# how to assign data from text file into structs c++

Tags: c++, stream, operator-overloading

I want to assign a content of a file into structs but I keep getting this error and if any one knows how to assign the data into the arrays of structs line by line please tell me also.

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' and 'const char [2]')
```

I do not know what is the problem. here is the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

struct StudentInfo {
    char fname[30];
    char lname[30];
    int id;
    char address[30];
    char PhoneNumber[20];
};

void read_file() {
    ifstream data("text.txt");
    StudentInfo array[11];
    if(!data.fail) {
        int i;
        for(int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
            data >> array[i].fname;
            data >> array[i].lname;
            data >> array[i].id;
            data >> array[i].address;
            data >> array[i].PhoneNumber;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
            cout << array[i].fname >> " " << array[i].lname << " " << array[i].id >>
                " " << array[i].address >> " " << array[i].PhoneNumber;
        }
    }
}

void print_student(StudentInfo s) {
    cout << s.fname >> " " << s.lname >> " " << s.id >> " " << s.address >>
        " " << s.PhoneNumber;
}

void search(StudentInfo array[]) {
    int sid;
    //    string last;
    cout << "Enter id";
    cin >> sid;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if(array[i].id == sid) {
            print_student(array[i]);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    StudentInfo array[11];
    read_file();
    search(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<= 11` ... out-of-bounds

Answer (score 4):

This statement

```
cout<<array[i].fname>>" "<<array[i].lname<<" "<<array[i].id>>" "<<array[i].address>>" "<<
            array[i].PhoneNumber;
```

does not make sense. In fact due to using the both operators << and >> in this part

```
cout<<array[i].fname>>" "
```

of the statement you have

```
std::cout >> " "
```

but the operator >> is not defined for the output stream std::cout.

It seems you mean

```
cout<<array[i].fname << " "
                     ^^^
```

everywhere in the statement where you by mistake are using the operator >>.

Pay attention to that if you have an array with 11 elements

```
StudentInfo array[11];
```

then the valid range of indices is `[0, 11 )`. That is using the index 11 you are accessing the memory beyond the array.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 11; i++) {
            data >> array[i].fname;
            //...
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all,  your iteration will be out of index

```
for (int i=0; i<=11;i++) // it would try to access invalid index
for (int i=0; i<11;i++)  // you should try this instead
```

Secondly, you have to correct the line as follows:

```
if(!data.fail) // It won't work
if(!data.fail()) // You have to use this
```

Thirdly, you have to change this line as follows as well

```
cout<<array[i].fname>>" "<<array[i].lname<<" "<<array[i].id>><<array[i].address>>" "<<
        array[i].PhoneNumber;   // This line should be removed
cout<<array[i].fname<<" "<<array[i].lname<<" "<<array[i].id<<" " <<array[i].address<<" "<<
        array[i].PhoneNumber; // This line should be added
```

Comment: Note: `if(!data.fail())` would be better as `if(data)`

Comment: @TedLyngmo agreed.